# MySQL service doesn't start in Catalina OSX

Tags: catalina, mysql

Installed MySQL 8.0.18 from a dmg file downloaded from the official site. The service won't start when manually started from the new Preferences icon added by the installer. Running `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start` dies with this error message:

> Starting MySQL .. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file

I tried setting file and dir ownership of `/usr/local/mysql/` to the `_mysql` user, and giving write permissions to `/usr/local/mysql/data/` as per other answers suggested but that didn't fix the issue.

**Edit:** Forgot to make clear this is on macOS Catalina, I think this is highly relevant as this version brought revised security policies setting how/if each app can write to disk.

Answer (score 3):

After hours investigating I found this post from Michael Fraase: https://discourse.brew.sh/t/mysql-8-0-18-on-catalina-wont-run-as-service/6015/2

I just added:

```
[mysqld]
user=root
```

to `/etc/my.cnf` (or where you have your `.cnf` file) and it solved it (I can not believe it).

Answer (score 1):

I solved like this:

1. Remove MySQL completely
   Watching: https://gist.github.com/vitorbritto/0555879fe4414d18569d
2. Install MySQL with Download do MySQL community server

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

And Done! Successfully!

Answer (score -1):

For mac OS `Catalina` :

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -uroot -p
```

This will prompt you to enter password of `mysql`